# Use different memory capacity RAMs in mac mini

Tags: memory, mac-mini

I have a mac mini with 2GB RAM and want to buy another stick (since mac mini only have to memory slots) of 4GB (all other specs are the same), will it cause a problem?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Can you tell us what version of the mini you are going to upgrade. The older versions (pre 2010) are rather difficult to open up.

Comment: See if this is your model, and you can see the difficulty: http://macminiramupgrade.com

Answer (score 2):

You need to find out what RAM your computer is capable of handling before you just start putting RAM into it, even if the speeds are the same, it's never to much trouble to be careful and do a bit of research to make sure things go smoothly.

Thankfully there are a lot of websites that have already tested these things for you so that you don't make any mistakes.  I usually go to:

http://www.crucial.com/store/drammemory.aspx

They have a system scanner service that will scan your system and check your settings, it will redirect you to a page where you can buy RAM, you don't have to obviously, but it will show you all the RAM configurations that your system supports.  It will let you know the max RAM capacity, if you don't see 4GB as an option, then it doesn't support it.

If you don't want to use the scanner you can also just input your make model year and cpu to get the same results, though the scanner is usually more accurate if you aren't sure which machine is yours. They do tests to make sure the RAM is compatible and list all the speeds and configurations for the RAM so you know which ones to get.  Make sure everything matches up before hand.

Knowing these things will help you find out if the RAM you have or are about to purchase will work so that you don't waste your time.  I hope this information helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, it shouldn't. I have a Mac Mini 2009 that I replaced with 2 X 4GB of RAM, with absolutely no problem. You may get a warning that your RAM is not optimally configured, but it shouldn't actually cause any errors (unless you don't install it correctly).

Comment: 2 x 4GB is (potentially) different from 2GB + 4GB, though.

Comment: True. However, I installed them one at a time (I previously had 2 X 1GB) and everything worked fine. I don't know about the warning because I don't know what OS version he has.